# How can I display a Progress at start up application in android

Tags: android, progress

I want to display a progress when the application start, then close progress when all data load completely. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **ProgressDialog** to *show Progress*, **Thread** to *load data* and **Handler** to handle *refresh UI*. 
In onCreate,

```
  mProgressDlg = ProgressDialog.show(this, "App_Name", "Loading data...", 
                    true, false);
  new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            /*Load Data*/
            mProgressDlg.dismiss();
            hRefresh.sendEmptyMessage(REFRESH);
        }
    }).start();



Handler hRefresh = new Handler(){

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       switch(msg.what){
         case REFRESH:
                /*Refresh UI*/
                break;
       }
    }
};
```