# create a ProgressDialog when i click on a button

Tags: android, onclick, progressdialog

I would like to pop up a ProgressDialog when I click à button. By clicking on this button it starts parsing an XML file and show the result in a ListView.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
// --- NEWS BUTTON
    OnClickListener newsButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
    {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View actuelView)
      {

        // Navigation to another screen
        Intent intent = new Intent(Lausanne_HC.this, NewsViewController.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Lausanne_HC.this, "", 
                  "Loading. Please wait...", true); 

      }

   };
   ImageButton newsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.newsButton);
     newsButton.setOnClickListener(newsButtonListener);
```

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/ This will help you . If you are not going for any sort data fetching from server through web service call. Than you have to implement a simple thread and make it sleep of desired amount of time which is in millisec. eg. 3000 ms = 3 secs

Answer (score 1):

Button click

```
Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

            public void onClick(View v) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                openprogresdialog(); 
            } 
        });
```

Create a this method.

```
private void openprogresdialog() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show( 
                HidekeybordActivity.this, "Testing", "Please wait...", true); 

        new Thread() { 
            public void run() { 
                try { 
                    // xml parser code here put... 
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                } 
                progDailog.dismiss(); 
            } 
        }.start(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the Intent to open another Activity, Android leaves the current Activity. If the Activity your opening with the Intent is the Activity which shows your parsed data, you should do the following:

1. Open your ProgressDialog
2. Start a new Thread to parse your XML
   file
3. After the file is parsed, kill the
   thread and use the Intent to show
   the data

I found [this older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596390/android-progressdialog-progress-bar-doing-things-in-the-right-order) on almost the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code that generate the `ProgressDialog` in the very start of the called Activity. Then use another thread to parse your XML file and generate the `ListView`, after the work is done, dismiss the `ProgressDialog`.

All these code should be put in the Activity that shows the `ListView`, since the `ProgreeDialog` is presented the progress of the XML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                    FastMainActivity.class);

            SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            //overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                //  android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

            SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();

        }

    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT); // SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH=3000
```