# how to show progressdialog at start of activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I hava an activity which might have to load data when it's starting up.

I've read some other questions and they all involved passing the progressdialog to the asycntask ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458190/how-can-i-display-a-progress-at-start-up-application-in-android) which has to load the data and close it after it's done. this is no option for my application since the method getNewData starts up 5 asynctasks and returns when they're all done.

Anybody has an idea how i can make sure the progressdialog is shown? atm the screen just stays black until the application is done loading.

```
ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading...", "Loading data", true);
dataCommunicator.getNewData(this);
pd.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a main `AsyncTask` inside which you can have the other threads running in `doInBackground()`. Show the `progressDialog` in this main `AsyncTask` `onPreExecute()`.

Maintain an int variable which can be accessed across the child `AsyncTask` and update its value as the child completes its operations. When that int is equal to 5 return from the main `AsyncTask` `doInBackground()` and dismiss the `progressDialog` in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: thank you, this wil fix it. such an obvious solution don't know how i could have overlooked it.